# AIOGRAM Возможно ли отредактировать предыдущей текст так, чтобы можно было добавить фотку

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Скорее всего, плохо сформулировал вопрос, но сейчас объясню более подробно и нормально.
Отправляю сообщение в aiogram с помощью message.answer. Хочу позже отредактировать сообщение так, чтобы к нему прикрепилась фотография. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: а "позже" это какой промежуток времени?

Comment: При нажатие кнопки "Фото"

Comment: это было уточнение к вашему "Хочу позже отредактировать сообщение". В телеграме нельзя редактировать сообщения старше 24 часов и если ваша задача подразумевает такую возможность, то лучше сразу от нее отказаться и пользоваться например `message.reply`